# What command could I use to get the table of values?

Tags: tables

I want to get the table of values as in the following link :

[Table](http://www.oberstufeninformatik.de/info12/wdhlg/Ackermann.pdf)

I wrote the following part of code:

```
   \central
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | }
    \hline
    \foreignlanguage{english}{m} \setminus \foreignlanguage{english}{n} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  & \dots & \foreignlanguage{english}{y} \\ \hline
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & \dots & \foreignlanguage{english}{y}+1 \\ \hline 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7  & \dots & \foreignlanguage{english}{y}+2 \\ \hline
    2 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 11 & 13  & \dots & 2\foreignlanguage{english}{y}+3 \\ \hline
    3 & 5 & 13 & 39 & 81 &  &  &    \dots & 8 \cdot 2^{\foreignlanguage{english}{y}}-3\\ \hline 
    4 & 13 & 65533 &  &  &  &  &   \dots &  2^{2^{.^{.^.}}^2}-3\\ \hline 
    5 & 65533 &  &  &  &  &  &  \dots  & \\ \hline 
    \dots &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \dots  &\\ \hline 
    \end{tabular}
```

Is it correct?? Could I improve something??

Comment: This seem  a  simple `tabular`  enviroment.  Any introductory text  to LaTeX explain well how to make tables. Read  about it somewhere, try to do this   table, and if you get stuck at some point, show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: this is just a standard tabular or array, a _really_ basic question covered by any latex tutorial.

Comment: I added the part of the code that I wrote. Could you take a look at it and tell if it is correct?? Could I improve something??

Comment: Note that you can have  `l`, `r`  or `c` columns, not with the number "1".  Besides this, change any `\foreignlanguage{english}{y}` by `y`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin = 3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathdots}

\begin{document}

\noindent Before.

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
 \label{table:something}
  \begin{tabular}{
         >{$}c<{$}
    *{2}{S[table-format = 5]}
    *{2}{S[table-format = 2]}
    *{2}{S[table-format = 3]}
  }
   \toprule
    A(m,n) & {$n = 0$} & {$n = 1$} & {$n = 2$}             & {$n = 3$}                 & {$n = 4$}                     & {$n = 5$}                         \\
   \midrule 
    m = 0  &     1     &     2     &  3                    &  4                        &   5                           &   6                               \\[1ex]
    m = 1  &     2     &     3     &  4                    &  5                        &   6                           &   7                               \\[1ex]
    m = 2  &     3     &     5     &  7                    &  9                        &  11                           &  13                               \\[1ex]
    m = 3  &     5     &    13     & 29                    & 61                        & 125                           & 253                               \\[1ex]
    m = 4  &    13     & 65536     & {$2^{\num{65536}}-3$} & {$2^{2^{\num{65536}}}-3$} & {$2^{2^{2^{\num{65536}}}}-3$} & {$2^{2^{2^{2^{\num{65536}}}}}-3$} \\[1ex]
    m = 5  & 65536     &           &                       &                           &                               &                                   \\[1ex]
    m = 6  & {$2^{2^{2^{2^{\iddots}}}}\raisebox{1.2ex}{$\Bigr\}$\,(\num{65536}~mal)}-3$} & & & & &                                                          \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\noindent After.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

A few suggestions:

- Use the [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to align the numbers in the table. (Also, use the package if you have physical units.)
- Use the [`booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to get a better thickness of -- and spacing around -- the horizontal rules.
- Use the syntax `*{<number of columns>}{<column type>}` where possible to shorten the code.
- Structure the input code to make it look like the output to get a better overview of it.

P.S. If you want a captions to the table, use the [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package with the option `tableposition = top` to get better spacing between the caption and the table.

Comment: When we write this part of code why does nothing else appear at the page where the table is??

Comment: @MaryStar I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I have written the code above and after the table I have written a sentence. But this sentence appears before the table. Why does this happen?? Also at the page of the pdf where the table is, there is only the table and nothing else, for example the sentence that I wrote is on the previous page...

Comment: Use the table option `htbp`.

Comment: Do you mean that instead of `\begin{table}` I should use `\begin{table}[htbp]` ??

Comment: Have you tried that before asking?

Comment: Yes, but I see no difference...

Comment: On my computer everything is fine. You should ask a separate question about this where you include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @MaryStar Or just don't put it in a `table` environment if you don't want it to move. Just start with `\begin{tabular}` and end with `\end{tabular}`.

Comment: @cfr Then you can't add a caption.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg You can with something like the `caption` package or `capt-of`.